# Filter JSON outer objects including only one maximal object from inner array with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a slightly modified JSON file with iOS firmware information from https://api.ipsw.me/v2.1/firmwares.json. This is a simplified version:

**Input**

```
{
  "AppleTV5,3": {
    "firmwares": [
      {
        "version": "9.2",
        "buildid": "13Y234"
      },
      {
        "version": "9.1.1",
        "buildid": "13U717"
      },
      {
        "version": "9.1",
        "buildid": "13U85"
      }
    ],
    "bdid": 52,
    "name": "Apple TV 4 (2015)"
  },
  "AppleTV3,2": {
    "firmwares": [
      {
        "version": "8.4.1",
        "buildid": "12H523"
      },
      {
        "version": "8.3",
        "buildid": "12F69"
      }
    ],
    "bdid": 0,
    "name": "Apple TV 3 (2013)"
  },
  "AppleTV3,1": {
    "firmwares": [
      {
        "version": "8.4.1",
        "buildid": "12H523"
      },
      {
        "version": "8.3",
        "buildid": "12F69"
      },
      {
        "version": "8.2",
        "buildid": "12D508"
      }
    ],
    "bdid": 0,
    "name": "Apple TV 3"
  }
}
```

I want to write a jq query that returns each outer object with only the latest firmware object in the `firmwares` array. E.g.:

**Desired output**

```
{
  "AppleTV5,3": {
    "firmwares": [
      {
        "version": "9.2",
        "buildid": "13Y234"
      }
    ],
    "bdid": 52,
    "name": "Apple TV 4 (2015)"
  },
  "AppleTV3,2": {
    "firmwares": [
      {
        "version": "8.4.1",
        "buildid": "12H523"
      }
    ],
    "bdid": 0,
    "name": "Apple TV 3 (2013)"
  },
  "AppleTV3,1": {
    "firmwares": [
      {
        "version": "8.4.1",
        "buildid": "12H523"
      }
    ],
    "bdid": 0,
    "name": "Apple TV 3"
  }
}
```

I can get a list of the latest `firmwares` objects with:

```
.[].firmwares | max_by(.version)
```

I can get just the values from `version` with:

```
.[].firmwares | map(.version | values) | max
```

And I can get the outer AppleTV objects with `firmwares` matching a particular `version`:

```
[ . | to_entries[] | .value.firmwares |= map ( select ( .version == "8.3" ) ) ] | from_entries
```

But I can't seem to combine the techniques to get my desired output. Can anyone help out?

Comment: @jq170727 Please stop adding json tags to already answered jq questions. Tags are meant to attract answers, these questions are answered well enough and you are basically farming rep. This is frowned upon and I will be rejecting your future edits in this vein. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164510/massive-redundant-retagging

Comment: @WillBarnwell I can see from your comment and the link that my activity bothers you and led you to believe my intent was to farm reputation and for bothering you I apologize.  From my history over the past month you can easily see I've spent considerable time reviewing and answering jq related questions and over the holiday weekend I found about 100 that I believe would benefit from a [json] tag.  I think people searching for help with json problems would benefit if those [jq] questions included the tag.  My question to you and the community is, what's the right way to go about this?

Comment: @jq170727 I also saw and admire your work around jq questions (a tool I also love), I know you are not just a bot and have guessed you had good intentions . However the meta question I linked and this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging discourage unnecessary tag edits. Tags are used to expose experts to questions which need answering/more attention. People with the same question will find it based on the title/question text, which will definitely involve 'JSON'. Additionally, all [jq] questions will be about JSON, so the tag is not bringing greater visibility from relevant experts.

Comment: @WillBarnwell That page says "You should re-tag questions when: You are replacing obscure or difficult to understand tags with well-known and popular tags that are appropriate for the question."  I think `[jq]` definitely qualifies as a relatively obscure tag compared to `[json]`.  But rather then debate this here I've posted https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356180/what-is-the-proper-way-to-go-about-suggesting-tags-to-100-questions and will hold off suggesting tags until folks have had a chance to weigh in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think of it as updating the `firmwares` arrays.  We're updating it with a filtered version where it the max version is selected.

```
.[].firmwares |= [ max_by(.version | split(".") | map(tonumber)) // empty ]
```

Comment: Just note that the version is lexically sorted. If you want more robust sorting, you'll need to break out each number, parse it, and sort against those.

Comment: I tweaked the filter to sort the version numbers numerically.  So version `10.1` will always come after `5.9`.

Comment: `split` and `fromjson` both require jq >= 1.4 and I'm running 1.3 at the moment (Fedora 22). Probably worth upgrading considering 1.5 is out ... Thanks again.

Comment: You should definitely look into updating. Though, this particular case didn't need `fromjson`, it really needed `tonumber`. You might be able to implement a version of `split/1` if you really needed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which uses **reduce** to visit each key of the object and update corresponding `.firmwares` to the latest version

```
reduce keys[] as $i (
    .
  ; .[$i].firmwares |= [max_by(.version)]
)
```